# Android Menu icons don't appear in the release build but display in the debug build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources, android-build

I am facing one of the most bizarre issues in rcent times. I am using AppCompatActivity with android support v7. When I am running the app in debug mode I can see the menus with icons, after generating signed apk and installing, the icons vanishes from menu.

1) [Release Build screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyAhY.png)

2) [Debug build screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYCjW.png)

Here is my menu code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".TerminalActivity">


<item android:id="@+id/action_streamConnect"

    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_stream"
    android:visible="false"
    android:title="Connect to Stream">
</item>

<item android:id="@+id/action_connect"

    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_bluetooth_connect"
    android:visible="true"
    android:title="@string/action_connect">
    </item>

<item android:id="@+id/action_disconnect"
    android:title="@string/action_disconnect"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_bluetooth_disconnect"
    android:visible="false"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_pulse"
    android:title="Start Pulse"
    android:icon="@mipmap/finger"
    android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_resp"
    android:title="Respiration"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:visible="true"

    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_lungs"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_activity"
    android:title="Track Activity"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:visible="true"

    android:icon="@mipmap/icon_activity_track"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_myRecords"
    android:title="My Records"
    android:visible="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_download"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_customUrlAnalyze"
    android:title="Analyze Record"
    android:visible="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_link"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="Settings"
    android:visible="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_settings_black_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    >

</item>

<item android:id="@+id/action_crlf"
    android:title="@string/action_crlf"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:visible="false"
    app:showAsAction="never" />


<item android:id="@+id/action_customer"
    android:title="Link Aadhar"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_card"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"/>
<item android:id="@+id/action_bank"
    android:title="Policy Purchase"
    android:visible="false"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_buy"
    android:title="Get Device"
    android:visible="true"

    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

I use a custom theme. Here is my theme style

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->


    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
    <item  name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/background_light</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>

</style>
```

In AndroidManifest I have included this AppTheme. I have also checked if I have used multiple Launcher intent or not
Please have a look at the Manifest

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TerminalActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        </application>
```

After failing to get any solution or understaning what I am doing wrong, I tried to follow the instructions from several Stack overflow answers.

Here are some of the random things I did:

Modified the default icon size in dimens.xml

```
 <dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size" tools:override="true">24dp</dimen>
```

All my menu icons are 24dp. I though may be that could be a problem as Android probably expects a 48dp icon for mdpi. So I checked by replacing few icon with even 48x48 icon size or even 96x96 size.

I tried to checnge the color to icons in runtime to see if the icons are redrawn.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_terminal, menu);

    for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++){
        Drawable drawable = menu.getItem(i).getIcon();
        if(drawable != null) {
            drawable.mutate();
            drawable.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }
    }



    actionConnect = menu.findItem(R.id.action_connect);

    actionDisconnect = menu.findItem(R.id.action_disconnect);

    camPulseMenu= menu.findItem(R.id.action_pulse);
    menuActivityTracking= menu.findItem(R.id.action_activity);
    this.menu=menu;

    return true;
}
```

All works fine in my debug but none in release build.

I also tried changing release settings in gradle. Here is my full gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.rupam.biosignal"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.5"
    generatedDensities = []

}

aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources true
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.macroyau:blue2serial:0.1.5'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
    compile 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:face:1.2.5'
    compile 'com.nabinbhandari.android.utils.permissions:android-permissions:1.0'

compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar')

compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar')
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/macroyau/maven"
    }
}
```

My activity extends AppCompatActivity.

I know I am making some silly mistakes, but can't find it.

Can someone please help me understand what is wrong here? Why icons dont appeak in menus?

PS: I tested With Samsung Galaxy, Moto G, ViVO and about 7-8 such devices but without any luck.

Comment: Provide you full gradle please.

Comment: I have edited my question and added ful gradle

Comment: Step 1.: look into the apk what you install on the device (and icons are missing). Dig down all the way to the res directory and verify that the icons are there, including all resolutions. I notice that the dimensions are different of the icons which manages to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are [**Shrinking**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) your resource in the release build.

please try to have the normal build type :

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
```

Comment: You are legend. That did the trick. Also I noticed that debug-apk was 1.6MB where as release-apk was only 1 MB. Just a question though, why even after setting ShrikResource as false in release it was shrinking resources and after setting it true in debug it was not shrinking?

Comment: @RupamDas because `minifyEnabled` work alongside for code shrinking.

Answer (score 0):

```
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

add this in the proguard-rules.pro file

Answer (score 0):

When you want to leave the option `shrinkResources` on, you can create `keep.xml` and make a list of the resources you wish to keep or discard. The build does not package this file into your app.

Base on [Documentation regarding how to shrink, obfuscate, and optimize your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-resources)  you need to create `keep.xml` in `res/raw`:

[image: res/raw/keep/xml]

Inside this file

> specify each resource to keep in the `tools:keep` attribute and each resource to discard in the `tools:discard` attribute. Both attributes accept a comma-separated list of resource names.

For example you can provide one file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@drawable/company_logo" />
```

or more files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@drawable/company_logo,@mipmap/car" />
```

You can also use the asterisk character as a wild card:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@layout/fragment_*,@layout/activity_not_used" />
```

There is also option `tools:discard`, which works in the same way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:discard="@drawable/free_version" />
```

or you can use them together

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@drawable/version_paid"
    tools:discard="@drawable/version_free" />
```

> Specifying which resources to discard might seem silly when you could instead delete them, but this can be useful when using build variants. For example, you might put all your resources into the common project directory, then create a different keep.xml file for each build variant when you know that a given resource appears to be used in code (and therefore not removed by the shrinker) [...]

Answer (score -1):

after doing some research it seems not related to the style or XML tag `app:showAsAction="always"` or shrinking or minifyenabled
the problem comes from the code inflation when displaying the menu

the below code resolves this issue

```
 val menuHelper: Any
    val argTypes: Array<Class<*>?>
    try {
        val fMenuHelper = PopupMenu::class.java.getDeclaredField("mPopup")
        fMenuHelper.isAccessible = true
        menuHelper = fMenuHelper[popupMenu]
        argTypes = arrayOf(Boolean::class.javaPrimitiveType)
        menuHelper.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("setForceShowIcon",
                *argTypes).invoke(menuHelper, true)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```